# Understanding rate function values in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, metrics, rate

I have read Prometheus function block docs, but sometimes I do not understand rate function actual values.

Let's say if we want to compute an average time of http service request over 60 sec, it would look like that:

```
sum by(uri) (
  rate(http_client_requests_seconds_sum[60s])
  /
  rate(http_client_requests_seconds_count[60s])
)
```

So it's an average time of finished request during these time series, measurement: Duration(s). It makes total sense to me. Now I want to calculate count changing of http_client_requests_seconds_count over 60 sec.

```
sum by(uri) (rate(http_client_requests_seconds_count[60s])
```

And let's say it gives back result (assuming metrics are sent to prom every 10 in the ideal world)

---

1.16, 1.20, 1.45, 0.8, 1.4, 0.1

---

What are those values? Increased count per 10 seconds, but how? percents? If I use `increase` function, at least it gives some visual numbers, that over 10 seconds the number of requests is increased by 2. But I don't get what rate function returns and why is it used in such cases so widely?